# Access denied creating xml file in apache tomcat

Tags: ajax, xml, jsp, tomcat

I am creating an Exam Portal, in it there is a JSP `calcresult.jsp` which calculates the result of exam and shows the result also after that it creates an xml file which stores the result so that examiner can evaluate the result later.
here is the code for xml generation :

```
<%
              DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = 
  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = 
 documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
  Element rootElement = document.createElement("Exam_Report");
  document.appendChild(rootElement);

  Element em = document.createElement("Name");
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(session.getAttribute("userid").toString()));
  rootElement.appendChild(em);

  em = document.createElement("Exam_Id");
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(session.getAttribute("examid").toString()));
  rootElement.appendChild(em);

  em = document.createElement("Paper_id");
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(session.getAttribute("paperid").toString()));
  rootElement.appendChild(em);

  em = document.createElement("No_Of_Ques");
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(request.getParameter("qid")));
  rootElement.appendChild(em);

  em = document.createElement("No_Of_Correct_Ques");
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""+right));
  rootElement.appendChild(em);  

  em = document.createElement("Total_Marks");
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""+tmarks));
  rootElement.appendChild(em);

  em = document.createElement("Marks");
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""+marks));
  rootElement.appendChild(em);

  em = document.createElement("Percentage");
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""+percentage));
  rootElement.appendChild(em);

  em = document.createElement("Result");
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result));
  rootElement.appendChild(em);

  TransformerFactory transformerFactory = 
  TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
  StreamResult result1 =  new StreamResult("CreateXML.xml");
  transformer.transform(source, result1);
            %>
```

everything works fine but when i run the page it shows an exception(Access Denied). 
Well of course when i have to create a new page or file in server directory then i require administrative authority so what i did was to use absolute path which doesn't have any 
 restriction like **`C:/xml/CreateXML.xml`**  which really worked but now i am not able to access this xml page through AJAX.
So what is the best way to solve this problem. Any help will be really appreciated.
And well i am using Apache Tomcat as server.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to write a servlet to return the content of the XML file. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/servlet-code-to-download-text-file-from-website-java/)'s an example for a text file. For an xml file you should use "text/xml" as content type.

But a better way imo would be to avoid the creation of a local file and send the XML "on the fly" directly from the servlet. You can find an example [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/359946/Servlets/java/Return-XML-HTTP-frm-servlet) (the post is old but the code is still valid).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but sorry i was not able to understand it.Maybe because i lack enough knowledge,but it would have been much better if you could explain those examples and the way it will help me, but still +1 for your time you give to answer :)

Comment: And yes i was expecting answers that could have allowed me to create XML file in the server directory, actually question should have been "how can i change apache servers settings to allow access to create a file" as simple as that